# Proxy Pass not working

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am attempting to get ProxyPass to work on my OpenSUSE 13.1 install.

I have tried:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_connect
systemctl restart apache2
systemctl reload apache2
```

(All combinations of statements to no avail).

I keep getting the same error over and over:

```
SERVER:/etc/apache2 # apache2ctl start -f /etc/apache2/httpd-proxy.conf
AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/httpd-proxy.conf:
Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

httpd-proxy.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/subsite
    ServerName www.site.com/subsite
    ProxyPass /subsite/ http://localhost:81
    ProxyPassReverse /subsite/ http://localhost:81
</Virtualhost>
```

Does anyone know how to get this ProxyPass statement working?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

it looks like `proxy_http_module` isn't getting loaded, make sure you have following inside of your `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: or `a2enmod proxy_http` if that's how your Apache works

Comment: @Mark you're being redundant, op have same exact line in the question..

Answer (score 2):

make sure that mod_proxy is enabled, and that it is loaded BEFORE mod_proxy_http. Apache doesn’t support dependency management of modules, so they have to be enabled in the appropriate order.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/apache/